# The command \pause on beamer!

Tags: beamer

When i put the command \pause on my beamer, the subsections are "white completely" (before appearing) while i want that they are "shaded" !

Do you have a solution for that ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Adding \setbeamercovered{transparent} should result in the expected output.

Comment: @leandriis  thanks for the answer, i add it before every \pause or just in the begenning ?

Comment: It is working thank you very much !!!